# Create text inside rectangle with border and shadow in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I've just started using the Jetpack Compose and I need to create a text inside rounded rectangle border with shadow. Is there a way to do this? I tried to put the text in a box, I can add the rounded rectangle shape, but not the border and shadow.
It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun RoundedCornerChip(
    content: String = "Basket ball",
    contentColor: Color = Color.LightGray,
    borderColor: Color = Color.Black,
) {
    val shape = RoundedCornerShape(60)
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize().border(shape = shape, width = 2.dp, color = borderColor),
        shape = shape,
        elevation = 10.dp,
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize(),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = content,
                color = contentColor,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.W800,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 30.dp, vertical = 10.dp),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

[image]

```
@Composable
fun TextInsideBoxScreen() {

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.border(width = 2.dp, color = Color.Blue, shape = CircleShape)

        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Basketball",
                color = Color.LightGray,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.W800,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 30.dp, vertical = 10.dp)
            )
        }


    }

}
```